# can't work xx.py using crontab

Tags: python, sensor

I can send the value to [domoticz](http://domoticz.com/) but the problem is that it just changed when I use the command

```
sudo python distance.py
```

I have added

```
* * * * *   /usr/bin/python /home/pi/domoticz/scripts/distance.py
```

in crontab.

And I use

```
sudo service cron start
```

to make it work. Beside, I add `+x` to the python.

This is the first of my file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import json
import urllib
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
```

But sadly, it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Including the libraries you're using is incredibly unhelpful to your question. Why would you include that and not the actual logic?

Comment: What and where is the code for `xx.py` and `distance.py`. How did you add it to crontab with which user?

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking of Python's environment variables. Make them exported in a system-wide **and** root shell profiles and also check PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables - make them specified manually and *restart the whole system*, i.e. reboot/powercycle it. Then it will work